# Meteor: best practice for creating database

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In my Meteor application, in `lib` folder (the folder that all code will be executed first). I create a file name `database.js` which contains:

```
tblUser = new Mongo.collection("Users");
tblComment = new Mongo.collection("Comments");
```

By use this way, I think:

1. `tblUser` and `tblComment` is global variable, so can access like we get a table from database.
2. If this is first run, Users collection, Comments collection, ... will be created automatically. If not, I can get already created tblUser and tblComment document from database.

Are 2 above assumptions right ? If wrong, please correct me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct, you just gotta remember about good pub/sub code.

Although, if you still got autopublish package then yes, your Collections are something like tables that hold same data as server, you just gotta `fetch()` them like `tblUser.find().fetch()`

Answer (score 1):

1. A meteor project have the autopublish and insecure packages. So, you should remove it and use a publish - suscribe policy in your application.
2. Remember, mongodb is no-sql, the collections don't will be created until you do the first insert.

Comment: Name of collection is in scope tho, so tlbUser.findOne() will be correct and return false, even though Mongo didn't create collection yet